# mongoexport could not connect to server with username issue

Tags: mongodb, aws-documentdb, mongoexport

```
mongoexport --host dbhost --port 27017 --db=mms-service --collection=document --type=csv --fields=_id --query='{}' --limit 10 --out exported.csv  -u=user.name --authenticationDatabase admin
```

but i get an error

```
could not connect to server: connection() error occured during connection handshake: handshake failure: username must contain a '.' separated database.user pair
```

what is the meaning of the error, it is the issue of the username, a dot in the username?

i also try to add quote to the username: "user.name", 'user.name', same error

**Update:**

1, also try mongo command, same error

```
mongo "mongodb://user.name:password@db-host:27017/?authSource=admin"

mongo --host dbhost --port 27017 -u user.name -p password --authenticationDatabase  admin
```

error message:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.13
connecting to: mongodb://dbhost:27017/authSource=admin&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: username must contain a '.' separated database.user pair :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

2, connect the db without auth, then auth by db.auth(), in this way, i can login into the db

```
mongo --host dbhost -p 27017
db.auth("user.name", "password")  -- the quote required
user dbname
show collections
```

it show the collections.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I see no error in your question, I think you pasted the wrong thing since you have the same thing twice.

Comment: sorry, pasted the wrong message, just pasted the collect one .

Comment: You may open a case at https://jira.mongodb.org. As workaround try [--uri=<connectionString>](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoexport/#std-option-mongoexport.--uri) -> `mongoexport --uri="mongodb://user.name@dbhost:27017/mms-service?authSource=admin" --collection=document --type=csv --fields=_id --query='{}' --limit 10 --out exported.csv `

Answer (score 0):

I came here and saw no answer, and flailed for several hours to find the solution. (feeling very much like this: https://xkcd.com/979/ ).

What ultimately resolved the issue was to add authMechanism='SCRAM-SHA-1' to the MongoClient parameters in python (or the equivalent option for mongo CLI).

In my case this issue appeared after migrating from Mongo engine 3 to engine 4